# How can I inspect a ValidationError exception while testing with django TestCase?

Tags: python, django, validation, testing

I'm working with Django testing using a django.test.TestCase and I would like to know the pythonic way to inspect a validation error. I've come up with the below, which works, but it feels a little long winded and prone to error over a large number of tests

```
    self.valid_account.contact_number = "1234567" # Too short
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        try:
            self.valid_account.full_clean()
            self.fail("Did not raise validation error")
        except ValidationError as e:
            self.assertTrue('contact_number' in e.message_dict)
            raise e
```

Is there a better way to inspect and test an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in using `assertRaises` if you're manually handling the exception. If you need to inspect the exception too, [the solution is documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

> The context manager will store the caught exception object in its exception attribute. This can be useful if the intention is to perform additional checks on the exception raised

So in your case this would look like:

```
self.valid_account.contact_number = "1234567" # Too short
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as cm:
    self.valid_account.full_clean()

self.assertTrue('contact_number' in cm.exception.message_dict)
```

Comment: Yeah that looks good, I had it in my head the the variable in the with block was temporary. Even so, not sure how I missed trying this.. - Thanks!